# Why does small tabla daaya breaks some time?

Tags: tabla

Why does the small daaya [tabla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla) break some times? And how to avoid it so that it does not break?

I have seen in many programs that they keep more than 1 daaya tabla but only 1 baya tabla.

Comment: You cannot avoid breaking it per se, but you can take precautions to not do it foolishly. The right drum is always have higher tension setting as it is high pitched, so it is more delicate instrument, and can vary pitch according to the weather patterns around. The answer below tells perfectly what to do and what not to do.

Answer (score 2):

The tabla is a delicate instrument. I assume you are asking about maintenance.

The [West London School of Tabla](https://www.wlstabla.co.uk/tabla-facts/) says:

> Tabla is a very delicate instrument. The following rules must be followed:
>
> Tabla should be kept away from extreme heat such as radiators or open fires. The cold also has a negative impact so avoid winter drafts and windows. Both conditions cause the skin to over stretch and eventually burst.
>
> Keep the tabla upright at all times.
>
> The top of the tabla should be kept clean with cotton wool.
>
> Cover the top part of both Dayan and Bayan with Gaddians (the rounded shaped padded cushions) before storing. This will help to keep the tabla top skin dry and will protect from dust and moisture.
>
> Do not play tabla with wet hands. If you sweat while playing, dry your hands and use ordinary talcum powder on your palm before playing.
>
> The tabla is best tuned at a lower pitch for storage as extreme dryness may hamper the instrument causing the skin to burst.
>
> Do not attempt to tune the tabla. This should only be carried out by your teacher or expert.